# Error Running Matplotpp with C++

Tags: c++, graph

I'm trying to run matplotpp (https://code.google.com/p/matplotpp/) inorder to output graphs on Lubuntu. Once downloaded and installed, I try to run my code but end up getting this error:

> graph.c:2:22: fatal error: matplotpp.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.

My code, **graph.c**, looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<matplotpp.h>
using namespace std;

class MP :public MatPlot
    {
        void DISPLAY()
            {
                vector<double> x(100), y(100);
                for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
                    {
                        x[i]=0.1*i;
                        y[i]=sin(x[i]);
                    }
                plot(x,y);
            }
    }mp;

void display()
    {
        mp.display();
    }

void reshape(int w, int h)
    {
        mp.reshape(w,h);
    }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutCreateWindow(100, 100, 400, 300);
        glutDisplayFunc( display );
        glutReshapeFunc( reshape);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;O
    }
```

The compiler terminates when it reads the "**include matplotpp.h**" line.
I've also tried "**include matplotpp/matplotpp.h**" but no luck. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you should use include"matplot.h" not <matplot.h>

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `include<>` and `include""`. When we use the latter one it. It first searches your own custom headers then go to system's own header file. And when we use the former it directly looks into system's header file. So, when you are using `<matplotpp.h>`, it goes to look in the system specific headers, and it is not present there. So you should use `"matplotpp.h"`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Unfortunately I did that initially but faced the same problem. I only changed it in my attempts to debug it.

Comment: If it's something that interests you... You can get matplotpp and compile it in under 3 minutes and test it out to see what you get.

Comment: Ok. Give me the link of matplotpp

Comment: Can you also give me GL folder of yours. i dont have glut. installed on my machine